# NMinimize reports no points satisfy constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Set

```
f[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ] := 5
```

and attempt

```
NMinimize[{f[a, b], a>0.1 && a<0.2 && b>0 && b<10 && Element[b,Integers], {a,b}]
```

The response is

```
NMinimize::nsol: There are no points that satisfy the constraints {}.
```

Yet if you try

```
NMinimize[{f[a, b], a>0.0 && a<0.2 && b>0 && b<10 && Element[b,Integers], {a,b}]
```

you get

```
{5., {a -> 0, b -> 6}}
```

Function is smooth with all derivatives.

```
{5., {a -> 0.15, b -> 6}}
```

would seem like a reasonable solution to the first request in light of the second.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is worth reporting to Wolfram support. You can workaround the issue by using [`Mod`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mod):

```
NMinimize[
    f[a, b],
    a>0.1 && a<0.2 && b>0 && b<10 && Mod[b,1]==0,
    {a, b}
]
```

> {5., {a -> 0.145338, b -> 9.82944*10^-9}}

Comment: this doesn't satisfy `Element[b,Integers]` though.